# Android/Xamarin code obfuscation

Tags: xamarin

I'm evaluating some tools to obfuscate an Android App. I'm trying to obfuscate a group of dlls (these were successfully obfuscated individually) to integrate them in a Android/Xamarin solution, but i don't know how to generate a apk file with the obfuscated dlls. Do you have any tutorial or guide to use this some tool with Xamarin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes take a look to this page http://www.nullskull.com/a/10477393/obfuscating-xamarin-applications.aspx hope it helps you

Comment: You should summarise the relevant parts of the page which you linked to.

Comment: It will work Fine if you are using Visual Studio to Compile de APK, but i could not find a way to do this using Xamarin Studio.